# Redshift dateadd() function error white casting the time value from varchar to time

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, casting, amazon-redshift, dateadd

I am executing the query using workbench in RedShift Database and I am receiving the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aKiA.png). I am unable to find the solution for same.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift dateadd() function operates on date or timestamp data types, not time data type. You didn't show the value in "arrival_time" so it is unclear which type you need.  If arrival_time is date plus time then just cast it to timestamp instead of time.  If this string has just time in it you will want to add an interval, not use dateadd(). Something like:

```
cast(arrival_time as time) + interval '1 hour'  -- doesn't work due issue described in comments
```

This approach will also work for timestamps.

EDIT: pulling up corrected code from comments to answer body for clarity.

```
cast(cast('2000/01/01 '||arrival_time as timestamp) + interval '1 hour' as time)
```

Comment: I have use the shared cast function but its give me  error                                                                                        [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Not implemented 
Details: -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Not implemented
  code:      1001
  context:   '!func_info->is_nullable_' -  function: time_pl_interval(), funcID = 1747
  query:     5605192
  location:  cg_expr_fn_builder.cpp:2476
  process:   padbmaster [pid=32128]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 2.69s

Comment: column Aarrival_time is string type and have only time in string format like this  "10:30:00" I want to add one hour in this time and it would we like "11:30:00"

Comment: Interesting - while "select cast('10:30:00' as time) + interval '1 hour';" works, sourcing the string from a table does not (RS oversight?).  Working in timestamps and casting to time works - "cast(cast('2000/01/01 '||arrival_time as timestamp) + interval '1 hour' as time)" is valid.  Your original use of dateadd() will also work just cast the string to timestamp and then the result to time - "cast(dateadd(hour, 1, cast('2000/01/01 '||arrival_time as timestamp)) as time)".

Comment: No any luck,            [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Timestamp out of range. 
Details: -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Timestamp out of range.
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     5619461
  location:  funcs_timestamp.cpp:219
  process:   query0_125_5619461 [pid=4972]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 1.25s

Comment: Query is                      select arrival_time, cast(dateadd(hour, 1, cast(arrival_time as timestamp)) as time) as newt
from stg.t_stop_times
where trip_id = 't_1246330_b_616_tn_0'

Comment: WIth interval

select arrival_time, cast(cast(arrival_time as timestamp) + interval '1 hour' as time) as newt
from stg.t_stop_times
where trip_id = 't_1246330_b_616_tn_0'

given 

This Error

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Timestamp out of range. 
Details: -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Timestamp out of range.
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     5619493
  location:  funcs_timestamp.cpp:219
  process:   query0_125_5619493 [pid=4972]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 1.28s

Comment: You left off the date being concatenated with the time -  "cast('2000/01/01 '||arrival_time as timestamp) ".  You have to give it a year, month, and day.  The casting back to time will strip the date part off.  Copy/paste the code given.